# multiple environment coremltools installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmake, path, coremltools

Trying to install coremltools. I installed using pip but that is not the most recent version and I have run into a bug that was solved 4 days so I must build from source. I'm on a Mac virtual desktop(windows user) and I tried cmake, but since there are multiple pythons it keeps trying to install to python 3.7 when I need it to install for python 2.7.10. The github suggest doing this:

```
   cmake . -DPYTHON=$(which python) -DPYTHON_CONFIG=$(which python-config)
```

.. however as someone who doesn't use cmake for package installs I'm unsure of the correct syntax could someone give me an example statement to go off of, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install it without building it manually:

```
pip install https://github.com/apple/coremltools/archive/master.zip
```

You can replace "master" with any branch or tag names.

EDIT: To update an existing install add the `-U` flag. Or uninstall previous installations.